# How do I install the Tenda U12 driver in Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: drivers

I’m new to Linux and I’m trying to get my Tenda U12 wireless network adapter to work but I can’t figure out how to install the driver. I already have the files on my computer, I just need help installing them. I’ve tried searching the issue and found a few articles but none of them helped me.

Comment: Please run `lsusb`, copy and paste the relevant line regarding the USB dongle in the question by [edit]ing it.

Comment: Where did you get the driver files from?